# EF4: AutoDetectChangesEnabled not found

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm in weired situation. I read about `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` and decide to use it.
But I cant found it. the code is

```
using (DefaultCS db = new DefaultCS())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            order.OrderTables = TableNo;
            order.OrderMenus = oMenu;
            db.Orders.AddObject(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I got error at `db.Configuration` which is `ROS.DefaultCS does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'ROS.DefaultCS' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

what I'm missing?
I'm using EF4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer: in Entity Framework 4 we should use `db.Orders.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;` instead of `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` which is only applicable in Entity Framework 5.

Code for EF4 and EF5

**In EF4**

```
db.Orders.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

**In EF5**

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

The downgrade for EF4 is to set it for each Entity.

Comment: If someone know better option to optimize L2E queries please share.